# Compiler ignores missing parenthesis of Exit command

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-xe

Why does the Delphi compiler ignore this missing parenthesis?

```
function Test: Boolean;
begin
  Exit(True;    // <-- eek! it compiles...
end;
```

I found some of my code looking like this and first thought that Delphi ignores my unit - but it just ignores this type of syntax error. So now of course I want to know why.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the compiler to me.

Comment: Same in XE2 update 4. Error Insight marks it though.

Comment: my guess it would be that since the function contains nothing else , it ignores the function itself. Try adding some code before the exit .

Comment: @CyprUS The context it came from was more complex. But I also played with it a bit. E.g. removing the semicolon as well makes it complain again.

Comment: Oh and **Yay** - a compiler bug *not* related to Generics!

Comment: in delphi 2006 gives the error "E2066 Missing operator or semicolon", probably a bug in xe2

Comment: @RBA The parameter for Exit was introduced in Delphi 2009 IIRC

Comment: Does not compile under Free Pascal 2.7.1, even in Delphi mode, FWIW (says **Fatal: Syntax error, ")" expected but ";" found**), so it does look like a compiler bug.

Comment: eek! MkII.  I didn't even know that Exit had a parameter now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `Exit` is considered a token unto itself, and as such anything defined within the same scope after `Exit` is simply ignored by the compiler (since it cannot execute those instructions anyway).

Comment: Adding instructions after the `Exit(True;` makes the compiler complain again with "E2066 Missing operator or semicolon" (Delphi XE).

Comment: I'd presume this is because the semicolon prompts the compiler to attempt to compile the next instruction.

Comment: Essentially I'm saying that `Exit` is an "absolute" token, prompting the compiler to disregard any subsequent chars on the same statement until the next occurence of the semicolon, which separates it from the proceeding instruction(s).
It's a quirk, for sure... and an interesting find!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the compiler is thinking that either
1. There is an Exit by itself, or
2. There is an Exit with a set of parentheses ().
If it doesn't find #2 it goes to #1.